# navigator.serviceWorker.controller always remains null

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I was doing some research with `serviceworkers`, I added a `serviceworkers` to my code:

sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (evt) {
    console.log("the worker was installed properly!");
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function (evet) {
    console.log("it has actived properly");
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (evt) {
    console.log("fetching some data");
    console.log(evt);
});
```

I'm using node(express) to server the code and this is my file structure:

```
-bin
-models
-public
 -mobile
  -images
  -js
  -css
  -fonts
   sw.js
   manifest.json
```

Here is how I am registering the serviceworker:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/mobile/sw.js', {scope: '/mobile/'}).then(function(reg) {
    console.log(reg);
    if(!navigator.serviceWorker.controller){
        console.info("controller is still none for some reason.");
        return;
    }
    console.log("worker is registered properly!");
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error("Something is not right, worker wasn't registerd");
    console.log(err);
});
```

}

The URL from where my index page is served is: localhost:3000/mobile.

The problem is `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` always remains null, the worker gets registered, I get a console for that. But when I check for `navigator.serviceWorker.controller`, it stays null.

I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Is it null also if you reload the page?

Comment: See https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues/104 where I went into some more detail.

Comment: I am facing a new issue, i'm not able to update serviceworker, I've mentioned full details over there. Could you please have a look..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding this code into my service worker:

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    clients.claim();
    console.log('Ready!');
});
```

That way, the navigator.serviceWorker.controller would be available

Source: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache/issues/104